# Unable to clone hosted Repository using NodeGit

Tags: git, git-clone, nodegit, node-github

I have created a GIT Bare Repository in the Linux server.

And while I try to clone the repository using Nodegit from the local workstation, I'm getting the following error.,

err  { Error: received unexpected content-type errno: -1 }.

Following is the apache access log,

/gitrepos/repository/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 59 "-" "git/1.0 (libgit2 0.25.0)"

This is returning "refs" as text.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output if you try `git clone url` command ? (also please edit your post with the URL of your repo to know whether it's http / https / ssh)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Finally I was able to clone the Repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I was able to sort out this Issue by myself.

It was an Issue with the Apache Configuration, where it was not processing the Request. After the Smart HTTP Protocol Configurations, everything works as charm.

Thanks,

Ramesh Gurusamy,